# I18n message multiline

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I search how to have a text in messages.properties on multiline

something like

> help.precision=It's cold ouside.

> Yesterday It's was minus 20.

I have very long text, with linefeed (more than 300 character).

Comment: Doesn't the word("\n") work?

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
help.precision=It's cold ouside. \
  Yesterday It's was minus 20.
```

An extra `\` at the end of first line will allow you to write multi-line strings in properties file.

Comment: If this answers your question, kindly accept the answer by clicking on tick mark.

Comment: In LibGDX that also uses i18n I had to use methods from both answers. You answer allows multiline text in property file but it still takes `\n` to get the actual new line in Java string.

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem you are trying to solve here is how to maintain a multiline string in .properties file.

mostly, .properties file work with java, so, we need to understand which letter (or combination of letters) are used in java to act as a new line markup.

In java "/n" is a newline character. So, if you add "/n" in the string, it will be processed as a newline giving a string the treatment of multiline string.

```
help.precision=It's cold ouside.\n Yesterday It's was minus 20.
```